# Showing that ~A cannot be derived from A

Tags: logic

If from the assumption of some A it follows that A is a theorem, then under threat of inconsistency of the system ¬A is not derivable from A. Is this statement true?

Comment: Reminds me of the Law of Non-Contradiction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction

Comment: @TurlocTheRed It's weird. My intuition is saying that it sounds right but I'm not really sure. If we assume A, then A is a theorem, so we can't derive ~A from it if we want the system to be consistent. And I don't know why but it feels like there's some foul play here.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you king I am so glad you're the one who looked over this

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA hold up, isn't this false if A is not a consistent statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ itself is inconsistent, then you can derive $A$ as well as $\neg A$ from $A$, and that is using a complete and consistent (sound) proof system.
For example, from $P \land \neg P$ you can derive $P \land \neg P$ itself, but you can also derive $\neg (P \land \neg P)$. Indeed, you can derive anything from a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, so the statement is not true if A is inconsistent, because in that case we could derive ¬A from it?

Comment: if so, is it enough for A to not be inconsistent for the statement to hold?

Comment: @Anon Yes, because if you can only derive a contradiction from an inconsistency. So, if you could derive both $A$ and $\neg A$ from $A$, then $A$ is inconsistent. So if $A$ is consistent, then given that you can (obviously!) derive $A$ from $A$, you cannot also derive $\neg A$.